# toggle row with specific attribute in jquery datatable on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm new to jquery datatable.

What I'm trying to achieve is, to toggle(hide/show) the row of datatable which is having attribute named `status_id` with value 9 to 13 on button click.

I have tried this for only number 9, but it's not working.

```
var dTable = $('#tbl_taskList').DataTable();

$(document).on('click', '.hide-tasks', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var row = dTable.row($(this).attr('status_id'));
    if(row === '9') {
        dTable.row().hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you make a demo?

Comment: Sorry to say,but I can't. @guradio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `hide()` feature for rows. Basically is what you are trying to do a specialized filter, so you could create a [custom filter](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) to achieve what you want. Here is an example of a toggleable filter which hide or shows `<tr>`'s with `status_id` 9 or 13 :

```
$('#hide-tasks').on('click', function (e) {
  //is the checkbox checked?
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    //add filter
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
      //always go through the API when working with dataTables!
      var status_id = parseInt(table.row(dataIndex).nodes().to$().attr('status_id'))
      return !~[9,13].indexOf(status_id)
   })
 } else {
   //reset filter
   $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop()
 }   
 //update table
 table.draw()
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/k1cz6rma/**

Answer (score 0):

Datatables docs says table.row hasn't hide fucntion but row().child() does.

```
var row = dTable.row(':eq('+$(this).attr('status_id')+')');

row.child().hide(); // hides

row.child().show(); // shows
```

checkout this page

[row().child().hide()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child().hide())